# Gradient descent optimization for multivariate scalar functions

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, scipy, gradient-descent

I attempted to test my gradient descent program on rosenbrock function. But no matter how I adjusted my learning rate (`step` argument), precision (`precision` argument) and number of iterations (`iteration` argument), I couldn't get a very close result.

```
import numpy as np

def minimize(f, f_grad, x, step=1e-3, iterations=1e3, precision=1e-3):
    count = 0
    while True:
        last_x = x
        x = x - step * f_grad(x)
        count += 1
        if count > iterations or np.linalg.norm(x - last_x) < precision:
            break
    return x

def rosenbrock(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

def rosenbrock_grad(x):
    """Gradient of Rosenbrock function"""
    xm = x[1:-1]
    xm_m1 = x[:-2]
    xm_p1 = x[2:]
    der = np.zeros_like(x)
    der[1:-1] = 200*(xm-xm_m1**2) - 400*(xm_p1 - xm**2)*xm - 2*(1-xm)
    der[0] = -400*x[0]*(x[1]-x[0]**2) - 2*(1-x[0])
    der[-1] = 200*(x[-1]-x[-2]**2)
    return der

x0 = np.array([1.3, 0.7, 0.8, 1.9, 1.2])
minimize(rosenbrock, rosenbrock_grad, x0, step=1e-6, iterations=1e4, precision=1e-6)
```

For example, code like above gives me `array([ 1.01723267,  1.03694999,  1.07870143,  1.16693184,  1.36404334])`. But if I use any built-in optimization methods in `scipy.optimize`, I can get very close answer or exactly equal `array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])` (this is the true answer).

However, if I use very small `step`, `precision` and very large `iterations` in my program, the calculation just takes forever on my computer.

I wonder if this is due to

> any bugs in my program

or just because

> gradient descent is inefficient here and demands very small
>   `step`, `precision` and very large `iterations` to yield a very close
>   solution

or because

> I need to do some special feature scaling.

*(Ps. I also tried to plot two-dimensional plot where value of function is on y axis and the number of iterations is on x axis to "debug" gradient descent, but even I get a nice-looking downsloping graph, the solution is still not very close.)*

Answer (score 2):

Your method is vulnerable to overshoot. In a case with instantaneously high gradient, your solution will jump very far. It is often appropriate in optimization to refuse to take a step when it fails to reduce cost.

## Linesearch

Once you have chosen a direction by computing the gradient, search *along* that direction until you reduce cost by some fraction of the norm of the gradient.

I.e. Start with x<sub>[*n*+1]</sub>= x - α * gradient

And vary α from 1.0 to 0.0, accepting a value for x if has reduced the cost by some fraction of the norm of gradient. This is a nice convergence rule termed the Armijo rule.

## Other advice

Consider optimizing the 2D Rosenbrock function first, and plotting your path over that cost field.

Consider numerically verifying that your gradient implementation is correct. More often than not, this is the problem.

Comment: Appreciated. I wonder if I chose a fixed learning rate but it's very small, will I still overshoot the problem after some iterations?

Answer (score 2):

To quote the [Rosenbrock Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosenbrock_function):

> The global minimum is inside a long, narrow, parabolic shaped flat valley. To find the valley is trivial. To converge to the global minimum, however, is difficult.

Gradient descent is a simple algorithm, so it is probably no surprise that it cannot find the minimum. Let's see what happens in 2D for different starting points:

[image]

Just as Wikipedia says: it easily finds the valley but then fails to converge further. The gradient along the valley is very flat compared to the rest of the function.

I would conclude that your implementation works correctly but perhaps the Rosenbrock function is not the most appropriate function to test it.

Contrary to other answers, I further argue that the step size is too small rather than too large. The problem is not overshooting but that the algorithm gets stuck. If I set the the step size to `1e-3` without changing other settings the algorithm converges to the maximum within two digits. This happens despite overshooting the valley from some starting positions in the 2D case - but you need the speed not to get stuck later on, so to say.

Here is the modified code to reproduce above figure:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def minimize(f, f_grad, x, step=1e-3, iterations=1e3, precision=1e-3):
    count = 0
    while True:
        last_x = x
        x_hist.append(x)
        x = x - step * f_grad(x)
        count += 1
        if count > iterations or np.linalg.norm(x - last_x) < precision:
            x_hist.append(x)
            break
    return x

def rosenbrock(x):
    """The Rosenbrock function"""
    return sum(100.0*(x[1:]-x[:-1]**2.0)**2.0 + (1-x[:-1])**2.0)

def rosenbrock_grad(x):
    """Gradient of Rosenbrock function"""
    xm = x[1:-1]
    xm_m1 = x[:-2]
    xm_p1 = x[2:]
    der = np.zeros_like(x)
    der[1:-1] = 200*(xm-xm_m1**2) - 400*(xm_p1 - xm**2)*xm - 2*(1-xm)
    der[0] = -400*x[0]*(x[1]-x[0]**2) - 2*(1-x[0])
    der[-1] = 200*(x[-1]-x[-2]**2)
    return der


k = np.linspace(0, 2, 101)
f = np.empty((k.shape[0], k.shape[0]))
for i, y in enumerate(k):
    for j, x in enumerate(k):
        f[i, j] = rosenbrock(np.array([x, y]))
plt.imshow(np.log10(f), extent=[k[0], k[-1], k[-1], k[0]], cmap='autumn')

for start in [[0.5, 0.5], [1.0, 0.5], [1.5, 0.5],
              [0.5, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.5, 1.0],
              [0.5, 1.5], [1.0, 1.5], [1.5, 1.5]]:

    x0 = np.array(start)

    x_hist = []

    minimize(rosenbrock, rosenbrock_grad, x0, step=1e-6, iterations=1e4, precision=1e-9)


    x_hist = np.array(x_hist)
    plt.plot(x_hist[:, 0], x_hist[:, 1], 'k')
    plt.plot(x0[0], x0[1], 'ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine you're hiking along a
[knife-edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Katahdin#Knife_Edge)
mountain path that's getting narrower and narrower. 
A **constant** step-size will take you over the edge, aieeeee;
you want to take shorter, more careful steps as you climb.
Similarly, to follow a Rosenbrock valley, a program must
take shorter, more careful steps as the valley narrows.
Decreasing step-sizes as step0 / t^0.5 or 0.25
helps GD on Rosenbrock a bit, 
but is still *very* sensitive to step0.

Real step-sizes aka learning rates must **adapt** to the problem terrain, e.g.
line search for smooth problems, Ada* for 
[SGD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) .

By the way, the Rosenbrock function is a sum of squares,
and there are powerful methods for that; see
[scipy.optimize.least_squares](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.least_squares.html) .